# Trying to find all unique values in specific part of string in Python

Tags: python, parsing, csv, url

I have a list of URLs that I am trying to parse and find the utm codes within each URL. I first want to find the unique values that come after utm, ie utm_source and create new columns with each of those values. The final thing I am looking for is something like

sourceUrl:
https://website.com/donate?utm_source=site&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=campaign1&uuid=999124&lang=en

source:
site

medium:
email

campaign:
campaign1

uuid:
999124

lang:
en

Right now I have the following:

```
import pandas as pd

email_list = pd.read_csv('/Users/rethompsoniii/Documents/Work-Related/Jeb 2016/email_list_20150804.csv', sep=',', header=0, error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')

url = email_list['SourceUrl']

utms = url.split("utm",1)[1]

print(utms)
```

However, the utms line is currently failing as well. Not looking for someone to give me all of the code, but just to point me in the right direction. Much appreciated

Comment: These are query attributes from a `url`. There is a Python library for this [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) library.

First you can parse the url to its corresponding components using the `urlparse.urlparse()` function.

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> url = "https://website.com/donate?utm_source=site&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=campaign1&uuid=999124&lang=en"
>>> parsed_url = urlparse.urlparse(url)
>>> parsed_url
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='website.com', path='/donate', params='', query='utm_source=site&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=campaign1&uuid=999124&lang=en', fragment='')
>>> parsed_url.query
'utm_source=site&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=campaign1&uuid=999124&lang=en'
```

From the parsed url you can parse the query using another function `urlparse.parse_qs()`

```
>>> parsed_query = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed_url.query)
>>> parsed_query
{'lang': ['en'], 'utm_campaign': ['campaign1'], 'utm_medium': ['email'], 'uuid': ['999124'], 'utm_source': ['site']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression.

```
import re
m = re.findall('utm_(\w+)=(\w+)', 'https://website.com/donate?utm_source=site&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=campaign1&uuid=999124&lang=en')
```

'm' is now a list with tuples:

```
[('source', 'site'), ('medium', 'email'), ('campaign', 'campaign1')]
```

But consider urlparse as Peter Wood mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use python [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) library.

**Sample:**

```
import urlparse
url = 'https://website.com/donate?utm_source=site&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=campaign1&uuid=999124&lang=en'
params = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(urlparse.urlsplit(url).query))
new_params = {key[4:] if key.startswith('utm_') else key:value for key, value in params.iteritems()}
print new_params
```

**Output:**

```
{'lang': 'en', 'source': 'site', 'medium': 'email', 'uuid': '999124', 'campaign': 'campaign1'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builtin library [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#module-urlparse).

First [parse the url](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urlparse):

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
>>> url = ('https://website.com/donate?utm_source=site&'
           'utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=campaign1&uuid=999124&lang=en')

>>> parsed = urlparse(url)
>>> parsed.query
'utm_source=site&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=campaign1&uuid=999124&lang=en'
```

Then parse the query string using [`urlparse.parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs):

```
>>> parse_qs(parsed.query)
{'lang': ['en'],
 'utm_campaign': ['campaign1'],
 'utm_medium': ['email'],
 'utm_source': ['site'],
 'uuid': ['999124']}
```